# How can I write/define different IDs to Mifare Classic 1k cards so that I can read them with rdm6300 card reader

Tags: smartcard, rfid, mifare, acr122

I'm using javaxsmartcardio at the moment but I don't know how this library works. I have an acr122u reader/writer and I only want to use it as writer so that I can write cards and read them on my RFID doorlock project with rdm6300 card reader. So far I've managed to read 2 cards which both were written to be used in social utilities. That's why I've written my arduino code according to 1 card is autherized and the other is not. But I want to write my own cards and put my own specific password so only the cards I give autherization will unlock the door. I'm all set with the doorlock part but I'cant write my own cards.Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mifare uses 13.56 MHz. The RDM6300 is 125 KHz.

You'll need to replace one to be compatible with the other for your project.

Comment: Thank you very much